# @Embeddable class with val in Kotlin

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I'm working on Gradle-Kotlin-Hibernate project. I would like to keep some of my classes immutable which in Kotlin is especially easy. This works just fine for *@Entity*

```
@Entity(name = "SOMETHING")
class MeetingKeychain(
        val immutableProp: String
) {

// ID and others

}
```

thanks to the usage of *kotlin-jpa* plugin. But the same plugin does not work for *@Embeddable*.

```
@Embeddable
class MeetingKeychain(
        val immutableProp: String
) {

// ID and others

}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:95)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate setter method for property [com.scherule.calendaring.domain.entities.ParticipantId#id]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findSetterMethod(ReflectHelper.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessBasicImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessBasicImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:42)
    ... 61 more
```

My question is that is there any way around this? I would like my *@Embeddable* class to be immutable.

Comment: Maybe this is related to this [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12985).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this proves to be doable and not related to Kotlin. The only way it is related is that you need to generate default constructor which what that *kotlin-jpa* plugin is used for. You need to use

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

while

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
```

is the default. Then it looks for setters rather than using field injections.

Comment: No, kotlin-jpa also handles `val` properties to allow hibernate use such classes without the need for setter and it works flawlessly on regular `@Entity` classes

Comment: @krzychek I had same error without field access. Was solved by adding field access. Can you share entity snippet and gradle/maven config for you project?

Comment: I don't have access to any projet with kotlin + jpa configured at the moment. Do you have kotlin-jpa plugin applied?

Comment: `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` seems to be required for embeddables with `val` (and not `var`) fields, even if the Kotlin JPA plug-in is in use. So, this suggested solution fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is Hibernate restriction. It clearly says `Could not locate setter method for property`. So we should provide setters for him. And the only way is to change `val` to `var`.
The `no-arg` plugin can't help here even if we add `@Embeddable` annotation to the plugin configuration:

`noArg {
    invokeInitializers = true
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}`